# Does the way that PageRank is heavily skewed lower the effectiveness of TF-IDF calculations?

Tags: information-retrieval

PageRank is heavily skewed in that a small proportion of webpages have a high PageRank score while most of the others have a very low PageRank score. **Does this undermine the effectiveness of the TF-IDF function?** For example, if PageRank scores were to be combined with TF-IDF scores, then for a few of the webpages, the TF-IDF would make very little difference, as they would have a high PR score, correct? And for the majority of the webpages with low PageRank, the TF-IDF score would tend to dominate, right?

Comment: Presumably it depends on how you combined PageRank and TF-IDF.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by "undermines the effectiveness of TF-IDF" when you're hypothesizing a combination of PageRank + TF-IDF -- undermines it, compared to what?

Comment: Google's full ranking algorithm is secret. I don't think we even know how it combines PageRank and TF-IDF, let alone variant of TF-IDF it uses, and what else it does.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any *theoretical* difficulty because of the skew of PageRank. For example, if PageRank values were linear, would it make it easier to combine with TF-IDF?

Comment: Well PageRank gives a certain score to websites. Now you can sort all the scores and give a website a score based on the index in this list. The transformation from some score distribution to a linear score is trivial. So no the skew of PageRank doesn't really matter and can be corrected easily.